# Deklinierung von Antezedens

Tags: loanword

Was ist die richtige Form vom Antezedens (im Sinn des Wenn-Teiles einer logischen Aussage) im Dativ Singular? Duden http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Antezedens gibt nur die Genitiv-Form an.

Comment: Mein Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass Dativ und Akkusativ unverändert gebildet werden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Antezedens](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=inflection&input=Antezedens&features=(Cat%20N)(Gender%20N)&country=D&lookup=caseInSensitive) wird wie folgt dekliniert:

- *Nominativ:* das Antezedens - die Antezedenzien
- *Genitiv:* des Antezedens - der Antezedenzien
- *Dativ:* dem Antezedens - den Antezedenzien
- *Akkusativ:* das Antezedens - die Antezedenzien